# select a point in chart and it shows the value

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I wanted to creat a macro that will point out the selected point in a chart. 
For example in a chart there is several point. But when i select a point in a chart it will show just the value for that point. i know that when i have mouse over the point it will show the points info but i wanted it to show all the time when i select it until i click some where else so it will be unmark. so i wonder how can i identify witch one of the point in chart is selected?

[image: example]

i manage to list all the point in the chart but i don't how to identify the selected point.

```
Sub test()
Dim pt As Long

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
     For pt = 1 To .Points.Count
          Debug.Print "Series 1 Point "; pt,Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(.Values, pt)
     Next
End With
End Sub
```

my vba skills is very poor

thx in advance

Comment: `my vba skills is very poor.` Have you tried anything at all? If so, please post what you have tried so we can help steer in the right direction!

Comment: you may need to write a separate class module for this. Here is a link that may get you started http://www.exceltip.com/show_tip/Events_in_VBA/Chart_object_events_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/439.html